# How to enter BIOS Debug on Sony Vaio VPCSB3AFX

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan, sony-vaio, proxmox

So I want to enable the "Wake on AC" or "Wake on LAN" feature on my BIOS, but the BIOS only displays limited settings. I tried to look for tutorials on different forums, but they say manufacturers lock it to avoid breaking the motherboard.

How true is that? Why not all laptop models have Advanced or Debug Settings on the BIOS.

My BIOS is Insyde Setup Utility Rev. 3.5, Sony Vaio VPCSB3AFX.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: What 'limited settings'? Pictures might be helpful.

Comment: It is somewhat rare for a consumer notebook to have WOL capabilities. Mostly because it is simply not necessary for most users.

Comment: On linux you can check if your network card supports WOL via `ethtool`

Comment: A photo would indeed be great. Maybe there is some switch to a more advanced mode that you missed. Still, it’s totally possible that there’s none.

Answer (score 0):

Most notebooks don't support WOL by hardware design, as for most consumers this feature is not necessary and also it is somewhat contradictory in a device designed for low power consumption.

While it is technically possible to implement WOL in a notebook, it also introduces additional complexity into the notebooks circuitry.

It may be possible that your notebook supports WOL and has no option to en-/disable it in BIOS.

As you are using linux, you can check the devices WOL capabilities via `ethtool`:

```
ethtool enp11s0f1

...
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
...
```

If the Line `Supports Wake-on:` says anything other than `d`, your device supports WOL.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I always read a tech tutorial that before you implement this, you must enable the "Wake on AC" first on the BIOS?